# Arduino IR Sensor Not Recieving

Tags: arduino, infrared

I am using an IR sensor with an arduino. I put the IR library into the correct folder. I am using the Example IRrecvDump just to test the sensor. When I plugged in the sensor, a red light turned on, indicating that everything is wired correctly. I am using a radio shack IR sensor. When I run my program, on the Serial it displays that it is ready to receive, however when I use a remote, the sensor never seems to receive anything. Below is the program I am using. Why is my IR sensor not recieving any signal? Please note, the following code IS NOT my own and I take no credit for it. I am just putting it here to show y'all.

```
/*
 * IRremote: IRrecvDump - dump details of IR codes with IRrecv
 * An IR detector/demodulator must be connected to the input RECV_PIN.
 * Version 0.1 July, 2009
 * Copyright 2009 Ken Shirriff
 * http://arcfn.com
 * JVC and Panasonic protocol added by Kristian Lauszus (Thanks to zenwheel and other people at the original blog post)
 * LG added by Darryl Smith (based on the JVC protocol)
 */

#include <IRremote.h>

/* 
*  Default is Arduino pin D11. 
*  You can change this to another available Arduino Pin.
*  Your IR receiver should be connected to the pin defined here
*/
int RECV_PIN = 12; 

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);

decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  Serial.print("Beginning recieve");
}


void dump(decode_results *results) {
  // Dumps out the decode_results structure.
  // Call this after IRrecv::decode()
  int count = results->rawlen;
  if (results->decode_type == UNKNOWN) {
    Serial.print("Unknown encoding: ");
  }
  else if (results->decode_type == NEC) {
    Serial.print("Decoded NEC: ");

  }
  else if (results->decode_type == SONY) {
    Serial.print("Decoded SONY: ");
  }
  else if (results->decode_type == RC5) {
    Serial.print("Decoded RC5: ");
  }
  else if (results->decode_type == RC6) {
    Serial.print("Decoded RC6: ");
  }
  else if (results->decode_type == PANASONIC) {
    Serial.print("Decoded PANASONIC - Address: ");
    Serial.print(results->address, HEX);
    Serial.print(" Value: ");
  }
  else if (results->decode_type == LG) {
    Serial.print("Decoded LG: ");
  }
  else if (results->decode_type == JVC) {
    Serial.print("Decoded JVC: ");
  }
  else if (results->decode_type == AIWA_RC_T501) {
    Serial.print("Decoded AIWA RC T501: ");
  }
  else if (results->decode_type == WHYNTER) {
    Serial.print("Decoded Whynter: ");
  }
  Serial.print(results->value, HEX);
  Serial.print(" (");
  Serial.print(results->bits, DEC);
  Serial.println(" bits)");
  Serial.print("Raw (");
  Serial.print(count, DEC);
  Serial.print("): ");

  for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
    if (i & 1) {
      Serial.print(results->rawbuf[i]*USECPERTICK, DEC);
    }
    else {
      Serial.write('-');
      Serial.print((unsigned long) results->rawbuf[i]*USECPERTICK, DEC);
    }
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    dump(&results);
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull of the PIN on which you put your signal (depending on which Arduino you use) because not all of them are able to send/recieve data (using interputs).

Comment: I already looked at that. I am honestly wondering if it is a bad sensor.